# SQL Server - best way to validate SQL schema and seed data

Tags: sql-server, validation, testing, schema

I am working on a web based app with a SQL Server backend. This is a somewhat legacy app that I've just begun working on a few months ago and the database versioning situation is a bit of a mess.

There is one set of scripts for a new install and another set for upgrading from version to version. Some of the scripts update the schema, others insert seed data. Other people, not developers, do the deployment and running of these scripts. Because of the versioning situation, there are sometimes issues with the scripts.

I'm revising the scripts to be more hardy, less likely to fail, and to have better logging when they do.

Meanwhile I want to do is create a validation script that we can run after a deployment. The script would runs and checks if all the necessary tables are there with the expected schema, and that the seed data scripts ran, everything is how it should be. Other than writing a ton of 'if not exists' (write to log) type statements, is there a better way to do this?

I can sometimes use Visual Studio schema compare to compare the newly updated database to an existing one, but data compare is not feasible in our environment.

Comment: Why not set up a database project starting with the new install, update each version and create a source control commit for each version. The final project would then be the one you deploy , unless you want an earlier version , which you can extract by checking out the particular version commit

Comment: We used tsqlt for testing. you can deploy test on both data and schema. if you use redgate, together with tsqlt you will be able to test new schemas and as soon as they are changed the way you dont expect your test cases will fail. Another way is to use red-gate source control together with git; the code compare and undo is really good

Answer (score 0):

I have the same situation on some of my projects and I use the following approach:
I have written the script which collects all significant data from DB (descriptions of tables, columns, their orders\types..., indexes, etc. and even stored procedures) as XML and after that calculates a hash of it. Then the script checks the calculated hash value against expected (calculated in development environment).

As result I have quite simple way to check a consistency of the DB as before development to ensure that I have an actual DB state as during test and production deployments to ensure that all expected changes were included into the release.

I suppose, you can use the similar approach but to include into a list of significant data some additional information to control seeding data too. Of course, to calculate a hash of all data into DB isn’t good idea, but if you know your DB you can find simple signs to control it (rows count, max Id, last modified date, etc.).

Answer (score -1):

Using INFORMAION_SCHEMA in the versioned database would be helpful for this.

1. First create a persisted table named DBSCHEMA to store all the versions of the database with an initial version of the database you want to track the changes (versions) in:

   SELECT ID=IDENTITY(int,1,1), TABLE_CATALOG, TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, 
   DATA_TYPE, ORDINAL_POSITION, '1.0.1' AS VERSION, GETDATE() AS VersionDate 
   INTO DBSCHEMA FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
   ORDER BY TABLE_NAME, ORDINAL_POSITION

Note: You can get more columns than you need from information schema for precision, text length, etc.  I did not include those.

2. With a subsequent change to the database schema, you will add a new version, Ex.  '1.0.2' and perform an insert of the new schema into the same table and increment the version each time.

   INSERT DBSCHEMA (TABLE_CATALOG, TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, ORDINAL_POSITION, 
   VERSION, VersionDate)
   SELECT TABLE_CATALOG, TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, ORDINAL_POSITION, '1.0.2', 
   GETDATE()
   FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
   ORDER BY TABLE_NAME, ORDINAL_POSITION
3. Now after you have multiple versions, you can check for changes between the versions with a query similar to the following to see what tables have changed in the database.  I would change this up depending on if I am looking for tables or columns that changed.

   SELECT T1.TABLE_NAME, T1.COLUMN_NAME from DBSCHEMA T1 INNER JOIN DBSCHEMA T2 ON 
   T1.TABLE_NAME = T2.TABLE_NAME
   WHERE T1.VERSION = '1.0.1'
   AND T1.Column_NAME NOT IN (SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM DBSCHEMA WHERE VERSION = '1.0.2') 
   OR  T1.TABLE_NAME NOT IN (SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM DBSCHEMA WHERE VERSION = '1.0.2')

The results of this query will give you changes that have occurred for tables and columns, but you can get more granular and check for data type, precision, etc. if you need more information. (There is probably a CTE query that would work better for this last query, but the one above gives you an idea of how to find the changes between the versions.)

Regarding the seed data, I would create another table for this that uses the same version as the one you inserted in DBSCHEMA and store the table name and count(*) of each table containing seed data.  This will allow you see if it is there, and/or if the count of seed data changed between versions.

Comment: The idea is good, but does not take into account things other than tables and column names changing.

Comment: Your explanation said 'checks if all the necessary tables are there with the expected schema, and that the seed data scripts ran' and did not mention other objects.  The solution I provided would account for those.  Even if this wasn't the complete solution, it didn't deserve a down vote.

Comment: I (OP) wasn't the one that downvoted, though I actually do need to compare all the schema objects not just tables, but it is still useful.